# Alternative characterisations of the Outer Measure $ \mu^*$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

In my lectures on Measure Theory, I came across the notion of an outer measure. The way in which this was presented to me was quite confusing and understanding this was quite difficult.

Having done some extra reading on this, I have found that there is a much simpler way to characterise outer measures that makes a lot of sense to me.

The definition that makes sense to me is the following:

> An **Outer Measure** is a function $\mu^* : P(\Omega) \rightarrow [0, + \infty]$ such that
>
> 1. $\mu^* (\emptyset) = 0$
> 2. $A \subseteq B \implies \mu^* (A) \leq \mu^* (B)$
> 3. $A_1, A_2, A_3, ... \in P(\Omega) \implies \mu^* (\cup _{n=1}^{\infty}A_n) \leq \sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \mu^* (A_n)$

After reading this definition and some surrounding explanation, this made a lot of sense to me.

However, the definition presented in my lectures is quite different and I am confused about whether or not these represent the same thing (and why they have decided to characterise the Outer Measure in this way). They use the following definition:

> An **Outer Measure** is a function $\mu^* : P(\Omega) \rightarrow [0, + \infty]$ such that for a countably additive measure $\mu$ and the set $D_E := \{(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} : A_i \in \mathscr{A}$ and $E \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \}$ we define:
> $$\mu^*(E) := \inf\limits_{(A_n) \in D_E} \sum _{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$ to be an outer measure.

This definition is very unclear to me, however, it is the only definition that has been presented to me in my lectures and so I don't want to try to build up an intuition for the previous definition if these are different in some way.

I would be grateful for some clarification here.

Comment: I think that what your second definition tells is the following: imagine a set in $\mathbb{R}$ that you cover with for example open intervals. You can add the lenghts of these intervals, but what you seek is the infimum of those sums.

Comment: That makes sense, but why are the two definitions equivalent? @JoséAntonio

Comment: They are not equivalent. The first definition you posted is an axiomatic definition, the second is a structure, defined for some measure $\mu$, which one can prove that satisfies the axiomatic definition. The second definition is a particular of the first one,

Comment: Thanks, that helps to clarify a lot. So this is just one example of an outer measure (ie. there are other examples of outer measures that are not induced by the second structure)? @user480840

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this come as a precursor to the Hahn-Extension theorem? Because that's where I've seen your second notion of an outer measure introduced.

Comment: Yes, that's where it was introduced. I hadn't come across Outer Measures before that, so I assumed that was just how it was usually defined @IrvingRabin

Comment: Ah OK. So then yes the whole proof of the Hahn-Extension theorem relies on showing that the set function you've written in definition two *is itself* an outer measure. Because once you know it's an outer measure it follows with some more work that you actually construct the extension with $\mu^\ast$ as in the second definition. But your first statement is the actual definition of an outer measure, the second is something *that happens to be* an outer measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\Omega$ has at least three points and consider the function $\mu^\ast \colon P(\Omega) \to [0, \infty]$ defined by
$$
\mu(A) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }A = \emptyset \\
1 & \text{if } A \neq \emptyset \text{ and } A \neq \Omega \\
3 & \text{if } A = \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
It is not difficult to prove that $\mu^\ast$ is an outer measure (in the first sense). Suppose by contradiction that there is a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ and a measure $\mu \colon \mathscr{A} \to [0, \infty]$ such that $\mu^\ast$ derives from $\mu$ as in the second definition. Then we assert that $\mu^\ast(A) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathscr{A}$ (this is an easy consequence of the second definition). It implies that $\mathscr{A} = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$. Indeed, if there is $A \in \mathscr{A} \setminus \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$, then
$$3 = \mu^\ast(\Omega) = \mu(\Omega) = \mu(A) + \mu(\Omega \setminus A) = \mu^\ast(A) + \mu^\ast(\Omega \setminus A) = 2$$
Next, the formula which gives $\mu^\ast$ in terms of $\mu$ implies that $\mu^\ast(A) = 3$ for all nonempty $A \subset \Omega$.

Therefore, the second definition is more restrictive. In fact, we say that an outer measure $\mu^*$ is *regular* if for all $A \subset \Omega$, there exists a $\mu$-measurable set $B \supset A$ (in the sense of Carathéodory) such that $\mu^*(A) = \mu^*(B)$. An outer measure $\mu^*$ satisfies the second definition if and only if it is regular, see for example [Federer's *Geometric measure theory*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-62010-2).